# How to display the image in almost full mode once clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code I wrote:

```
Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(URL).into(new CustomViewTarget<ImageView, Bitmap>(avatarImage) {

    @Override
    protected void onResourceCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
        progressBarAvatar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        avatarImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
        progressBarAvatar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final Bitmap circleLetterTile = tileProvider.getCircularLetterTile(fullName);
        avatarImage.setImageBitmap(circleLetterTile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
        progressBarAvatar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        final Bitmap circleAvatarBitmap = tileProvider.getCircularImage(resource);
        avatarImage.setImageBitmap(circleAvatarBitmap);
        avatarImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // code
        });
    }
});
```

It basically displays the user's image (in a circle) and a default one in case h does not have. Once user  clicks on the image, I want to open a sub-layout which just shows the image in **almost** full mode (like it usually done in contacts apps and even facebook) so you still see the activity as background (in grey color). How do I set an `setOnClickListener` so once clicked, it will open such layout and display the image? What would be the easiest way to achieve it?

Comment: Open your selected image in another activity by passing this image url

Comment: Are there any nice animations I could use for that?

Comment: You can use shared elements transition ref: [https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity]